# Pragmatic way for a C API to ensure that the user's resources remain allocate?

Tags: c, memory-management, ownership

I'm implementing a programming language. I want to offer a public API for some core tools of the language (tokenizer, parser, AST nodes, type inference, codegen, a number of checkers and more): a C library other developers can use to compile/process/analyze/generate programs using my programming language.

Users of this library should pass it a source program (a `char*` pointing to a nul-terminated string that contains a program) which must remain allocated while any of my library's components are used.

I believe it's bad design to request the user to keep the string allocated themselves. I also don't like the idea of creating a copy of the source program: it could be a large string and most times it's unnecessary to copy it. I believe the best solution is to let my library take ownership of the string.

However the string could be a static one, or allocated with by `malloc`, or allocated with `mmap` or even something else. So how is my library supposed to dispose of it during clean up?

What's the pragmatic way for a C API to do this?

Comment: Make a copy?  With something like `strdup()`?  Then  free it during cleanup?

Comment: I don't see any problem in passing a string that is allocated by the caller. This is pretty standard in C, the caller often has a lot of responsibility, see for example `man 3 strtok`. In your case your API functions should take a `const char *`. If you mean to say that you would need multiple calls to your library in order to parse the string, then you should make it clear to the users of the API.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show the declaration of your planned API functions with a short description.